# Getting my nested resource to work in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Can't seem to figure out what the problem is here. So I have a log model that has_many entries. In my routes, I have it set up as:

```
resources :logs, shallow: true do
  resources :entries
end

resources :entries
```

1) Do I need the separate entries resource at the bottom? It seems like I do with the forms that I am using.

In my log partial I have a table that then renders the entries partial with a link at the bottom for creating a new entry:

```
<tbody>
  <%= render(log.entries) %>
</tbody>

<%= link_to 'New Entry', new_log_entry_path(@log) %>
```

And the entries/_form.html.erb looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@entry) do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :log_id %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.select(:name, [['Bench Press', 1], ['Military Press', 2], ['Squat', 3], ['Deadlift', 4], ['Barbell Row', 5]]) %>
  </div>

  ...
  ...

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And finally, my controller code, I have a concern named CurrentLog:

```
module CurrentLog
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  private

    def set_log 
      @log = Log.find(params[:log_id])
    end
end
```

And in my Entry, the start of which is:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentLog
  before_action :set_log
  before_action :set_entry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /entries
  # GET /entries.json
  def index
    @entries = Entry.all
  end

  # GET /entries/1
  # GET /entries/1.json
  def show
    @entry = Entry.new
  end

  # GET /entries/new
  def new
    @entry = Entry.new(log_id: params[:log_id])
  end

  # GET /entries/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /entries
  # POST /entries.json
  def create
    @entry = Entry.new(entry_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.save
        format.html { redirect_to @entry.log, notice: 'Entry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @entry }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

NOW the problem is:

When I create, edit, or delete an entry, it does not correctly match the log_id (of 1 in this case) with the entry.

After creating a new entry with the form, instead of going to log/1/entries/xx, it goes directly to entries/xx, and does not carry the appropriate information from the form. What am I doing wrong here? Sorry for the long post, and I hope I was as concise as possible!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I managed to fix it by changing some of where the routes were directing in the link_tos.